# Note Statement Not Working When Going Through Multiple Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have Multiple Worksheets (coding VBA) where I am trying to create borders around the data (Columns A through J). However their is one Worksheet I do not want to be modified and that is the MasterSheet Worksheet. When I run the query the only table that gets modified is the Master Sheet. Provided code below:

```
Dim ft As Worksheet

For Each ft In Worksheets
If ft.Name <> "MasterSheet" Then


Range("A3:I3" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1, Weight:=xlThick

End If
Next ft
```

Comment: Qualify your `Range` and `Rows` calls with the worksheet: `ft.Range...` and `ft.Rows`.

Comment: You need to tell Excel which worksheet the Range belongs to, by using `.Range` rather than `Range`.

Comment: ^ Well you'd need `With ft` if you take this approach.

Comment: This helped! Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Dim ft As Worksheet

For Each ft In Worksheets
    If ft.Name <> "MasterSheet" Then
        ft.Range("A3:I3" & ft.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).BorderAround _ 
                ColorIndex:=1 _
               ,Weight:=xlThick
    End If
Next ft
```